# Invariance of the cylindrical Laplace equation under conformal transform

Tags: cv.complex-variables, conformal-geometry

hello,
it is often said that a **conformal mapping** preserves the Laplace equetion in 2D.
However, if this is true for the **cartesian coordinates (x,y)**, where the laplacian is:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial y^2}=0
$$

is it true for the **cylindrical coordinates (r,z)** where:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}=0?
$$

More precisely, if you have a function $\phi(r,z)$ verifying the previous equation, is it also verified by $\psi(u,v)$ is $u+i v=f(z+ir)$ and f is analytic/holomorphic?

Comment: How about
$$\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}=0
$$

Comment: Maybe the change of variables you want is $ue^{iv} = f(re^{iz})$ ...

Comment: To elaborate on Gerald's comment: the coordinate change you wrote down is not a conformal mapping [see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map ] in general. Also, this question has nothing to do with conformal field theory. 

Comment: but that is suited when you want to apply you conformal mapping to the $(r,\theta)$ plane and not the $(r,z)$ plane, or?

Comment: wait a second, what do you actually mean by the cylindrical coordinates in 2D? Are you actually interested in functions defined over 3 dimensional space but is constant along the azimuthal direction? 

Comment: my geometry is invariant by $\theta$ so i'm using a conformal map to transform a slice (r,z) with a complicated geometry into a slice of a cylinder (ie a rectangle) and i solve the cylindrical-laplace equation in this rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. Take $\phi=r^2-2z^2$ and $f(z+ir)=(z+ir)^2$, thus $u=r^2-z^2$, $v=2rz$. Then $\phi(u,v)=r^4+z^4-10r^2z^2$ is not cylindrical-harmonic.